# How can I connect to Datastore (Firestore Native Mode) using Javascript for a demo website?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I had managed to get a simple display page working using firebase and firestore however the firestore in GCP console doesn't seem to give me the details I need such as "authdomain" etc.

I've managed to convert my device simulator over to native GCP firestore which uses python however i cant seem to work out how to get the JS code to transfer over or where to get the additional details from (authdomain, databaseurl, storagebucket, messagingsenderid)

Has anyone tried to use a firebase in native mode with javascript and could point me towards some samples or documentation as all the docs on google either talk about firestore as part of firebase or firebase in datastore mode ... nothing seems to give examples for native mode!

Sample javascript code from google, but there's no explanation on where to find the details

```
// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '### FIREBASE API KEY ###',
  authDomain: '### FIREBASE AUTH DOMAIN ###',
  databaseURL: '### FIRESTORE DATABASE URL ###',
  projectId: '### CLOUD FIRESTORE PROJECT ID ###',
  storageBucket: '### STORAGE BUCKET URL ###',
  messagingSenderId: '### MESSAGING SENDER ID ###'
});

var db = firebase.firestore();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the config from the Firebase Console. Add Firebase to your GCP project [as described here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/client/get-firebase)(click `+ Add project` instead of import project.). Then you can follow these steps to view your config object:

1. Sign in to the Firebase console and open your project.
2. From the landing page, click `+ Add app`.
3. Select the `<\>` icon for web apps. This will show you the config object for your project.

More docs about this here: 
[Add Firebase to your JavaScript project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)